# Как сделать отправку сообщение каждый час?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot, schedule

```
elif message.text == 'Подписаться':

bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Подписка оформлена')
    
def son(message):

    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Я сплю')
    def zavtrak(message):
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Я Завтракаю')
    def rabota(message):
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Начинаю работать,делаю превьюшки,ютубчик все дела.')

        schedule.every().day.at("04:00").do(son(message))
        schedule.every().day.at("05:00").do(son(message))
        schedule.every().day.at("06:00").do(son(message))
        schedule.every().day.at("07:00").do(son(message))
        schedule.every().day.at("08:00").do(son(message))
        schedule.every().day.at("09:00").do(son(message))
        schedule.every().day.at("10:00").do(son(message))
        schedule.every().day.at("11:00").do(son(message))
        schedule.every().day.at("12:00").do(son(message))
        schedule.every().day.at("13:00").do(son(message))
        schedule.every().day.at("14:00").do(son(message))
        schedule.every().day.at("15:00").do(zavtrak(message))
        schedule.every().day.at("16:00").do(rabota(message))
        schedule.every().day.at("17:00").do(rabota(message))
        schedule.every().day.at("18:00").do(rabota(message))
        schedule.every().day.at("19:00").do(rabota(message))
        schedule.every().day.at("20:00").do(rabota(message))
        schedule.every().day.at("21:00").do(rabota(message))
        schedule.every().day.at("22:00").do(rabota(message))
        schedule.every().day.at("23:00").do(rabota(message))
        schedule.every().day.at("24:00").do(rabota(message))
        schedule.every().day.at("01:00").do(rabota(message))
        schedule.every().day.at("02:00").do(rabota(message))
        schedule.every().day.at("03:00").do(rabota(message))
```

Есть условие что если человек нажимает на кнопку "подписаться" то ему каждый час начинается отправляться сообщение из определенной функции. Как это реализовать? Я попробовал использовать schedule.Но как правильно с ним работать не понял, даже по методичке.При запуске бот выполняет отправку сообщения с подпиской,выполняет первую функцию son(Причем мгновенно) и выключается ,выдавая это

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\bossc\Desktop\Project\main.py", line 149, in <module>
    bot.polling()
  File "C:\Users\bossc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 485, in polling
    self.__threaded_polling(none_stop, interval, timeout, long_polling_timeout)
  File "C:\Users\bossc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 544, in __threaded_polling
    raise e
  File "C:\Users\bossc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 507, in __threaded_polling
    self.worker_pool.raise_exceptions()
  File "C:\Users\bossc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\telebot\util.py", line 117, in raise_exceptions
    raise self.exception_info
  File "C:\Users\bossc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\telebot\util.py", line 69, in run
    task(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\bossc\Desktop\Project\main.py", line 121, in next6
    schedule.every().day.at("04:00").do(son(message))
  File "C:\Users\bossc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\schedule\__init__.py", line 471, in do
    self.job_func = functools.partial(job_func, *args, **kwargs)
TypeError: the first argument must be callable
```

Не особо понял как это все реализовать. Может есть другой способ?

Comment: Есть пакет https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

Comment: "Может есть другой способ?" - других способов куча, но то что вы неправильный аргумент передаете еще не означает, что нужно искать другой способ)

Answer (score 6):

Используйте асинхронность, самый простой способ решения задачи

```
import asyncio


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

async def spam_start():
    while True:
        print("Какое-то сообщение")
        await asyncio.sleep(3) # время в секундах

loop.run_until_complete(spam_start())
```

Если таких человек много, то подобная реализация теряет смысл. Тогда нужно сделать скрипт, который будет запускаться раз в час, например с помощью cron, брать сообщения из бд и отправлять их кому нужно

Answer (score 0):

```
async def scheduler():
    aioschedule.every(30).minutes.do(start_function)
    #aioschedule.every(1).hours.do(start_function) каждый час
    while True:
        await aioschedule.run_pending()
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 0):

```
import asyncio
import aioschedule as schedule
import time

async def job(message='stuff', n=1):
    print("Asynchronous invocation (%s) of I'm working on:" % n, message)
    asyncio.sleep(1)

for i in range(1,3):
    schedule.every(1).seconds.do(job, n=i)
schedule.every(5).to(10).days.do(job)
schedule.every().hour.do(job, message='things')#Каждый час!
schedule.every().day.at("10:30").do(job)

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
while True:
    loop.run_until_complete(schedule.run_pending())
    time.sleep(0.1)
```

Читайте документацию https://pypi.org/project/aioschedule/